# css text ::selection with round corners

Tags: javascript, html, css, selection

I saw this selection in VSCode and monaco-editor and it looks really good :

[image]

SO I tried to recreate this, here is my effort :

```css
#ta{
  font-size : 18px;
}
#ta::selection{
  background : rgba(173, 216, 130, 0.9);
  border : 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius : 15px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="ta"></textarea>
```

But this doesn't get the round corners effect(I hope you get it) like the one shown in the picture.

Please help me out. Answers appreciated.

Comment: Looking up [`::selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection), there is only a very small subset of CSS rules that can be applied to it, `border-radius` not being one of them. In other words, this doesn't seem possible in this way. You might be able to use JS to wrap the [current selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) in a `span`, then add some `display: inline-block` and the desired `border-radius` to it, although this would probably not work in a `textarea`.

Comment: @domsson could you show me a attempt?

Comment: What is the question? Do you want rounded corners only on selecting the text area?

Comment: I need the ::selection to have rounded corners

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As some people already commented on your question

> [::selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection) is only a very small subset of CSS rules that can be applied to it, border-radius not being one of them...

So, next step is, if you really need it, how could you go around it? One of the options is:
You could use the "selected" string and then add some HTML tags. Then when you select text and release the mouse all your CSS styles will be applied.

Keep in mind: this might not work in "normal" text boxes

I hope the following code gives you an example to get started

```js
var selectionElements = document.querySelectorAll('.selection');
selectionElements.forEach(function(element){
    element.setAttribute('original-content', element.innerHTML);  // this will be needed to reset to original after a selection has been made
    element.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
        replaceContentWithSelectionWrapper(this)
    });
});

function replaceContentWithSelectionWrapper(element) {
    let selection = window.getSelection().toString();
    if(selection.length <= 0) { // if selection length is not bigger then 0 we can stop right here
        return;
    }
    // next lines should be self explanatory
    // get start of string until selection
    // get the end of string after selection
    // concatenate all strings back together
    let selObj = window.getSelection(); 
    let selRange = selObj.getRangeAt(0);
    let originalString = element.innerHTML;
    let start = originalString.substr(0, selRange.startOffset);
    let end = originalString.substr(selRange.endOffset);
    element.innerHTML = start + '<span class="mark-special-selected">' + selection + '</span>' + end;
    document.body.classList.add('selections-enabled');
}

function clearSelections() {
    var selections = document.querySelectorAll('[original-content]');
    selections.forEach(function(selection){
        selection.innerHTML = selection.getAttribute('original-content');
    });
}

document.body.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
    if(document.body.classList.contains('selections-enabled')) {
        document.body.classList.remove('selections-enabled');
        clearSelections();
    }
});
```

```css
.selection {
  font-size : 18px;
}
.mark-special-selected,
.selection::selection{
  background : rgba(173, 216, 130, 0.9);
  border : 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius : 15px;
  outline: 2px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="selection">Here is some text, you can select some of it with your mouse</h1>
<p class="selection">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
```

Comment: I couldn't fix the bug you found in mine and you seem to take the very same approach, so I deleted mine. However, yours doesn't work for me. Not sure why.

Comment: @domsson thank you for the feedback. I've tested in chrome and safari, where it works fine for me. Also updated so it works by now also in firefox. Can you please check if it works now or let me know more precise what does not work. Thanks

Comment: the first and most important issues is that only one out of two selections works. Every second selection just yields no highlighted text at all. The second and less important one would be that there is a brief, but noticeable moment (maybe half a second) where you see a rectangular selection which then changes to a rounded one. However, this is much better than yesterday, when I couldn't get any text to highlight. This is on Firefox 68.2.0esr / Linux.

Comment: Thank you again @domsson for your feedback! Yes FF did not work cause he handles the click mouse down clear things differently then chrome and safari. The rectangular to rounded problem occurs depending on when you release the mouse. We could improve it but I don‘t want to rewrite the selection behaviour in jvascript.. happy coding

Comment: Thank you a lot @caramba you did something which I thought would be impossible. +1m thanks a lot!!

Comment: Thank you a lot @domsson  you did something which I thought would be impossible. +1m thanks a lot!!

Answer (score -1):

With this CSS, the effect is more like the text selection of VS Code, it's just not instantly rounded and it doesn't have the effect on each intersection (and has a line of one pixel blank between lines, due to the lack of a border), but the text won't move when selecting it.

I remind that the text selection of [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) looks like this:

[image: Visual Studio Code text selection]

Other issues with the code snippet below:

- If the click is released outside of the text box, the rounded corners effect may not work;
- If the text is selected from outside the text box, the selection will be the default one;
- In this example, if the cursor selects the header text and releases the click on the text bellow, the upper selected text is written lower, and the effect is only on the lower paragraph;
- In this example, if the cursor selects the lower text and releases the click on the upper text, the lower selected text is written upper, and the effect works only on the selected copied part which is now in the header text;
- If the text is selected too fast (I think this is the cause of it), the rounded corners don't work on the header text.

Anyway, strange things are going on with this text selection, and if someone can handle them, it would be great.

```js
var selectionElements = document.querySelectorAll('.selection');
selectionElements.forEach(function(element){
    element.setAttribute('original-content', element.innerHTML);  // this will be needed to reset to original after a selection has been made
    element.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
        replaceContentWithSelectionWrapper(this)
    });
});

function replaceContentWithSelectionWrapper(element) {
    let selection = window.getSelection().toString();
    if(selection.length <= 0) { // if selection length is not bigger then 0 we can stop right here
        return;
    }
    // next lines should be self explanatory
    // get start of string until selection
    // get the end of string after selection
    // concatenate all strings back together
    let selObj = window.getSelection(); 
    let selRange = selObj.getRangeAt(0);
    let originalString = element.innerHTML;
    let start = originalString.substr(0, selRange.startOffset);
    let end = originalString.substr(selRange.endOffset);
    element.innerHTML = start + '<span class="mark-special-selected">' + selection + '</span>' + end;
    document.body.classList.add('selections-enabled');
}

function clearSelections() {
    var selections = document.querySelectorAll('[original-content]');
    selections.forEach(function(selection){
        selection.innerHTML = selection.getAttribute('original-content');
    });
}

document.body.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
    if(document.body.classList.contains('selections-enabled')) {
        document.body.classList.remove('selections-enabled');
        clearSelections();
    }
});
```

```css
.selection {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.mark-special-selected, .selection::selection{
  background: #8884;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="selection">Here is some text, you can select some of it with your mouse</h1>
<p class="selection">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
```